# Insert Into First Row Excel

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

I have an excel file that I run through access whereby it is filtered. I am trying to create an update query that adds a new row above the filtered data and enters the value "Filtered Values". However, I cannot seem to find the SQL statement to do so. Any insights?

I think something similar to:

```
INSERT INTO Cus (CusName) VALUES ('Filtered Values')
```

However, how do i ensure its inserted into row 1?

Comment: Why are you filtering in Access? Excel has plenty of options for filtering data.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is not clear. Are you trying to add new row in Excel sheet or are you trying to add data into Access database?

Comment: @KevenDenen I filter the data in access since I use it to generate reports.

Comment: @Maciej Los I am trying to add a new row in an access table using a query.However that table already has data, but I want to add the row as the first row above the data that is already there.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to insert data into MS Access database (table) at the beginning of the table. But you can sort data.

For further information, please see: [Save a sort order with a table, query, form, or report](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Save-a-sort-order-with-a-table-query-form-or-report-4f255441-7326-486a-97ad-7760e8b0880b)

Comment: What about inserting data in say the second row or any other row except the first one?

Comment: @Navron, As i mentioned, there is no way to insert data in first, second, etc. row.